# How to create unique folders for hundreds of documents (Mac)

Tags: macos, pdf, file-management, file-organization, organizer-software

I've got a few hundred (maybe even a thousand) PDF files; I'd like to have each of them in individual folders, ideally with a hierarchy I can design on the fly as I go.

Is there a reasonable way to carry this out that is faster than make new folder -> label, then drag in?

The depth of hierarchy might be a dozen or more. Some folders might have multiple files, but many are unique.

Would appreciate your thoughts SE!

Comment: Are you wanting to create a folder with the pdf name? Some other ID? Where are all the files at present (unsorted in a single folder?)? Personally I prefer tags for classifying (so files could be effectively in several virtual folders) - you can do similar with symlinks but it gets messy.

Comment: A folder with the pdf name would be very helpful, and yes they are in one single (unsorted) folder.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with a bash script like so:

```
for i in {1..1000}
do
    mkdir $i_folder
done
```

this will make 1,000 folders named 1 thru 1000. You can edit it to add your own names to the digits. You could add a mv command in do loop to move files into folders. Without knowing more about your files this is best I can do.

Answer (score 2):

Make a backup first of course!

```
for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.pdf" -exec basename "{}" .pdf \;); \
do mkdir $i; \
mv $i.pdf $i; \
done
```

The `find` just gets the files (-f) from the current directory (-maxdepth 1) which are named anything ending in ".pdf" ignoring letter case. It then takes the part of the filename before .pdf (basename) and holds this in a variable.

Then it makes a directory (`mkdir`) using that variable, so a file "AdobeFile.pdf" will make a directory "AdobeFile", then it moves (`mv`) the file to the directory.

I recommend **copying** a subset of files to a temp directory, operating on those, checking the files go where you want and then running on the full set.

I've not tested properly handling of filenames with spaces or . in them, nor with weird characters (like UTF8).

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged it "organizer software": without me knowing your planned hierarchy, or even you yourself not yet knowing the hierarchy, it might get difficult pretty fast. You can try this with smart folders, AppleScripts, or FolderActions. But in any case, the hierarchy needs to be reasonably well designed before you use these.
I would like to suggest using a specialised software for that task.

Depending on the types of PDF, the 'quality' of the filenames and the quality of the embedded metadata in them: 
There are many choices to do that.

EagleFiler, Yojimbo, DevonThink are not the only commercial contenders that come easily to mind.
Free applications that create an iTunes-like hierarchy for you might be found either in [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com), especially if the embedded metadata is of reasonable quality and the documents are more of a 'book' type, or [BibDesk](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net) if you can use identifiers like DOI, so it's more for scientific, journal-paper-type PDFs. 
Both offer a kind of auto-filing of PDFs. If find BibDesk exceptionally qualified for the task and quite customisable.